# gcloud crashed (IndexError): list index out of range

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a global ip address and want to attach it to a vm instance at creation, but get the following "**gcloud crashed (IndexError): list index out of range**". I even get a "**400**" error when I run "`gcloud feedback`" to report this error.

For the "`gcloud feedback`" command this is the error I get:

```
[25785:25785:0823/191930.556861:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[25751:25773:0823/191930.665881:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 8 ms for network service
Opening in existing browser session.
```

I don't know what this error is and the command used is:

```
gcloud compute instances create mydemovm --address="mytestip"
```

Are there limits to how global ip addresses can be attached to vms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a regional IP for VMs, as for global IP use them for global load balancers as per [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address?_ga=2.183299110.-1248134499.1625751800#reserve_new_static).

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this was the case